# Rewrite url with params

Tags: .htaccess

Below is the htaccess file I am using.I have a pagination url as `domain.com/?page=1` . Now this is getting only the first page records and does not fetch the next page records even though `domain.com/?page=2` passed to the url.
 I suspect it is due to the rewrite url because it is working fine on the localhost and on the server side it is fetches only the first page records.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

By changing the rewrite url to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,PT,L]`. It has solved my problem